# Check previous 5 and next 5 indexes in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking for a way to loop through an associative array but only echo when the previous 5 "statuses" are "CLOSED_FOR_SERVICE" and the next 5 "statuses" are "OPEN"

This is what I have come up with that works but it is by far not elegant. I am sure I need to use a for loop for each for the previous and then another one for the next ones but I can't seem to get my head around it.

[`$logRow` data](https://pastebin.com/9BuBuMrj)

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($logRow); $i++) {
    if (array_key_exists($i - 1, $logRow)){
        if (($logRow[$i]['status'] == "OPEN") && ($logRow[$i - 1]['status'] == "CLOSED_FOR_SERVICE")){
            if (array_key_exists($i - 2, $logRow)){
                if ($logRow[$i - 2]['status'] == "CLOSED_FOR_SERVICE"){
                    if (array_key_exists($i - 3, $logRow)){
                        if ($logRow[$i - 3]['status'] == "CLOSED_FOR_SERVICE"){
                            if (array_key_exists($i - 4, $logRow)){
                                if ($logRow[$i - 4]['status'] == "CLOSED_FOR_SERVICE"){
                                    if (array_key_exists($i - 5, $logRow)){
                                        if ($logRow[$i - 5]['status'] == "CLOSED_FOR_SERVICE"){
                                            if (array_key_exists($i + 1, $logRow)){
                                                if ($logRow[$i + 1]['status'] == "OPEN"){
                                                    if (array_key_exists($i + 2, $logRow)){
                                                        if ($logRow[$i + 2]['status'] == "OPEN"){
                                                            if (array_key_exists($i + 3, $logRow)){
                                                                if ($logRow[$i + 3]['status'] == "OPEN"){
                                                                    if (array_key_exists($i + 4, $logRow)){
                                                                        if ($logRow[$i + 4]['status'] == "OPEN"){
                                                                            if (array_key_exists($i + 5, $logRow)){
                                                                                if ($logRow[$i + 5]['status'] == "OPEN"){
                                                                                    echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", $logRow[$i]['time']).'<br />';
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so many `if` statements, you could have used `loops`...

Comment: show us the output of `echo "<pre/>";print_r($logRow);` . Please add it in question

Comment: My brain tends to explode a little when using loops so nesting isn't my strong point. I have also added the data for $logRow

Comment: please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why do you start the loop at 0 when you need five consecutive items prior? Same thing, don't loop all the way to the end. You can stop at count -4.

Comment: Post a `var_export($logRow);` and I can test.

Comment: To clarify, this can potentially `echo` multiple times? Or is it expected to stop at first match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, thought I would join in, but doing something which is completely different.  Rather than trying to match the arrays and having to worry about wrap around (some array methods will pick up the end of the array if you pass negative numbers), I decided to try and match strings...

```
$mangle = implode(",", array_column($logRow, "status"));
$toFind = trim(str_repeat("CLOSED_FOR_SERVICE,", 5).str_repeat("OPEN,", 5), ",");

$offset = 0;
while ( ($offset = strpos($mangle, $toFind, $offset )) !== false)   {
    $index = substr_count(substr($mangle, 0, $offset), ",");
    $index = array_keys($logRow)[$index+5];    // I do this because I extracted part of the sample data
    echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", $logRow[$index]['time']).PHP_EOL;
    $offset++;
}
```

So it builds up a string containing all of the statuses and then looks for the string of 5 CLOSED_FOR_SERVICE and then 5 OPEN's.  It then counts the commas up to the point at which it found this pattern (adds 5 as this includes the 5 CLOSED_FOR_SERVICE records).

It repeats the loop, carrying on from where it left off (the ++ makes sure it doesn't just find the same one again).

The `array_keys()` isn't needed if you have a full array, but as I mentioned in the comment, I extracted part of the data and so had non-sequential keys.

Comment: I really like this approach. non complicated and does what i need. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to test this (I'll try to soon), but here's the general idea:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($logRow); $i++) {
    if($logRow[$i]['status'] == 'OPEN' &&
       ($prev = array_slice($logRow, $i - 6, 5)) &&
       ($next = array_slice($logRow, $i + 1, 5)) &&
       !array_diff(array_column($prev, 'status'), ['CLOSED_FOR_SERVICE']) &&
       !array_diff(array_column($next, 'status'), ['OPEN']))
    {
            echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", $logRow[$i]['time']).'<br />';
    }
}
```

- Loop and check current `status` for OPEN
- Slice previous 5 elements
- Slice next 5 elements
- Extract `status` elements from previous 5 and check for no difference with CLOSED_FOR_SERVICE
- Extract `status` elements from next 5 and check for no difference with OPEN

Maybe better with only one `array_column` call on the entire array unless it is huge.

Comment: I tested your answer and it does not work good. At least not the same way as Mattigins did (different output)

Answer (score 1):

This is my idea.
Don't loop the full array. start at 5, and end at count-4 because before and after this you wont have enough items to be true anyways.

Array_slice the ten items and compare against a "pattern array".

```
// i used 0 or 1 instead of closed or open but the idea is the same.
$arr = [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1];
for($i = 5; $i<count($arr)-4;$i++){
    if([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1] == array_slice($arr, $i-5, 10)){
        //echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", $logRow[$i]['time']).'<br />';
        echo "yes\n";
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/m4K7m

Answer (score -1):

Here you go.

```
for ($i = 5; $i < count($logRow) - 5; $i++) {
    $prev = array_slice($logRow, $i - 5, 5);
    $next = array_slice($logRow, $i + 1, 5);

    if (
        5 === count(array_filter($prev, function($row) {
            return 'CLOSED_FOR_SERVICE' === $row['status'];
        }))

        &&

        5 === count(array_filter($next, function($row) {
            return 'OPEN' === $row['status'];
        }))
    ) {
        echo date('F j, Y, g:i a', $logRow[$i]['time']).'<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/* =============================
 * PSEUDO CODE 
 * ============================= 
 */

// Initialize
open = 0
closed = 0
out = null
//Loop
foreach (array as line) {
  // Test for CLOSED_FOR_SERVICE 5 times consecutive occurences
  if (closed == 4) {
      // Capture target time and jump to next line
      if (out == null) {
         out = line[time]
         continue
      }
      // Start testing for OPEN statuses and count or reinitialize
      if (line[status] == 'OPEN') {
         open = open + 1
      } else {
         out = null
         open = 0
         closed = 0
         continue
      }

      // Bingo
      if (open == 4) {
         print out
         out = null
         open = 0
         closed = 0
      }
  } else {
      // Count CLOSED_FOR_SERVICE or reinitialize
      closed = line[status] == 'CLOSED_FOR_SERVICE' ? closed + 1 : 0
  }

}
```